# Property 'MathFun' is missing in type '(x?: number, y?: number) => number' but required in type 'Func'

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Not able to uderstand the error here:

`Property 'MathFun' is missing in type '(x?: number, y?: number) => number' but required in type 'Func'.(2741) input.tsx(3, 5): 'MathFun' is declared here.`

```
interface Func {
    MathFun:(a:number,b:number) => number
};


const plus:Func = (x:number=30,y:number=40):number => x+y;
```

any one help me to understand? what is the correct way to declare `interface` for a function?

[Live URL](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQDECuYmoN7CpGoCyCEAFlmAFwAUCNYmAtgEawA0bTrHMASlQBeAHypm7WMAC%20AbmCKkAezABnCKgAOAG0xqa1XMNR0AHrykxhAZgAMnAJ6X%20wgCx2BL2CPFmA1I5yQA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function interface by leaving out the function name and replacing the `=>` with a `:` ([current docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#call-signatures), and a slightly clearer explanation in the [old docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#function-types)):

```
interface Func {
  (a: number, b: number): number;
}

const plus: Func = (x: number = 30, y: number = 40): number => x + y;
```

The interface you created is valid code, but it is for an object with a function property:

```
interface FuncObject {
  mathFun: (a: number, b: number) => number;
}

const plusObj: FuncObject = {
  mathFun: (x: number = 30, y: number = 40): number => x + y,
};
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIFcQOQbwFDLIAUcAXMiOgLYBG0ANMjeZbdAJQvV1QDceAXzx4EAexABnMMgAOAG3QTyGLMgC8xAB5c2UdcgDMABkYBPHT30AWI5wrdo6gHzJNyANTJT-YaEixEFBUEAHkaACsIBGl8Qio4MAALFXISCwYmdKh2Z3tdfiERcSlZBQkw8OVMUIio6Q1Y5HiklK0s-WMzdo0bO1ZLNRc3T1N6QX4gA)